# How can I run a TestCafe autotest on a page that requires certificate validation?

Tags: typescript, authentication, automation, ssl-certificate, testcafe

I need to use TestCafe to run an autotest on a page that requires certificate validation.
In my .testcaferc.json file I have added SSL certificates and when I run the test, first in the Chrome window I am asked to confirm that the connection is not secure, I accept it manually, and then I am redirected to localhost, where after a while in the URL- the address of TestCafe Chrome, I see https://localhost:4200/about:error after that my test restarts after some time but also not giving any errors

Here example of my code

```
fixture (`Info Page test`).page('www.google.com');

const infoPage = new InfoPage();
test('Check label on Info Page', async () => {
    await t.navigateTo('IP url')
    await t.wait(10000);
});
```

As soon as I run the test it loads and immediately crashes

1. I tried to make a workaround and use [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) page search to emulate user actions but to no avail.
2. I tried to add --ignore-certificate-errors when starting the test, but also without success.

```
"testcafe chrome --ignore-certificate-error tests/1.login-test.ts", //line in my package.json file
```

3. I tried to change the hostname and apply by hostname instead of IP. But it is also fruitless

Answer (score 1):

Starting from v3.0, TestCafe uses Native Automation mode in Chromium-based browsers by default. Native Automation mode supports HTTPS and HTTP/2 websites out of the box, so the `--ssl` option is not needed.

If you site uses an invalid certificate, you can use the `--ignore-certificate-errors` Chrome flag as you mentioned.

I believe that you just have a typo in this flag. Please try running your tests with the following command:

```
testcafe "chrome --ignore-certificate-errors" test.js
```